# Finally get my win 7 connected to strongSwan VPN, but there's no Internet

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I believe I've followed all the instructions, and my win 7 did get connected, but there's no Internet.

**Background:**

> **Server OS**: ubuntu 12.04 on linode xen VPS
>
> **strongSwan Version**: 4.6.4

configurations in **/etc/ipsec.conf** :

```
config setup
        charonstart=yes      
        plutostart=yes     
        nat_traversal=yes
        uniqueids=yes

conn ios
        keyexchange=ikev1
        authby=xauthpsk
        xauth=server
        left=%defaultroute
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
        leftfirewall=yes
        right=%any
        rightsubnet=10.11.0.0/24
        rightsourceip=10.11.0.0/24
        pfs=no
        auto=add

conn win7         
        keyexchange=ikev2
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
        esp=aes256-sha1!
        dpdaction=clear
        dpddelay=300s
        rekey=no
        left=%defaultroute
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
        leftauth=pubkey
        leftcert=serverCert.pem
        leftid="C=CH, O=strongSwan, CN=VPS ip"
        right=%any
        rightsourceip=10.11.1.0/24
        rightauth=eap-mschapv2
        rightsendcert=never
        eap_identity=%any
        auto=add
```

added dns in **/etc/strongswan.conf** :

```
charon {
dns1 = 8.8.8.8
dns2 = 208.67.222.222
...
pluto {
dns1 = 8.8.8.8
dns2 = 208.67.222.222
...
```

added user in **/etc/ipsec.secrets** :

```
: PSK "mypskpass"
user1 : XAUTH "pass1"

: RSA serverKey.pem
user2 : EAP "pass2"

#include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.secrets.inc
```

added some new rules in **/etc/iptables.firewall.rules**

```
*filter
# Accept IPsec VPN connections
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -s 10.11.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.11.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat

# Allow IPsec VPN connections

-A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

And then **activated iptables rules**:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules
```

Then **restarted ipsec**:

```
ipsec restart
```

Till this point, **my iOS devices can connect to it and everything works all right**.

After that I generated certificates for both server and client side, then converted .pem into .p12 and imported it into win 7.

The good part is that my win 7 can now connect to the vps, but there's no internet connection.

I really don't know which part went wrong, would anybody please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing but maybe you need to enable `arp` setting in `sysctl.conf`

Enable the following parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or the equivalent on your Linux distro):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_accept = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp_pvlan = 1
```